# Случайные числа srand

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Мне нужно генерировать случайное число для одной и той же переменной несколько раз в диапазоне 1 - 100. В плюсах есть ф. srand, но она генерирует случайное число только в начале программы. Из-за этого в переменной находится одно и то же число постоянно. Код:

```
    int main()
    {
        srand(time(0));
        int chance = rand() % 100;
        std::cout << chance << std::endl;
        std::cout << chance << std::endl;
    }
```

А мне нужно, чтобы после каждого вывода генерировалось другое число.

Answer (score 6):

Вы что-то путаете. Итак, `srand(time(0))` нужна для того, чтобы при каждом новом запуске программы последовательность случайных чисел была иной. Без него последовательность будет одинакова при всех выполнениях программы (что, кстати, полезно при отладке).

```
rand()
```

при каждом вызове выводит очередное случайное число. У вас оно сохранено в `chance` и больше вы эту функцию не вызываете. А зря :)

Попробуйте так:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int chance = rand() % 100;
    std::cout << chance << std::endl;
    chance = rand() % 100;
    std::cout << chance << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int chance = rand() % 100;
    std::cout << (chance = rand() % 100) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (chance = rand() % 100) << std::endl;
}
```

А кстати, можно напрямую в `cout'e` обновлять значение! Не забывайте про скобки, чтоб соблюдался приоритет!